# Total Resistance in a Tetrahedal loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrical-resistance

Imagine if I placed resistors of 1 ohm each in shape of tertahedal. What would the total resistance be between A and D?

I can't find any website that gives me a good explaination. 
[image: Tetrahedal Cirucit]

Comment: You mean: the resistance between any of the two vertices (like $A$ and $B$), correct?

Comment: Yes, between A and D.

Answer (score 2):

First redraw the schematic in 2D form so that it is easier to see the circuit:

[image]

Now the solution is obvious from inspection.  It's just the parallel combination of R1, R2+R3, and R4+R5.  You don't even need a calculator.

Comment: It would be better if you explain, how you arrived at the above modified circuit, sir.

Comment: You do understand that a wire has the same potential everywhere (until it meets a resistor) right?

Comment: @nervxxx: The electric potential at a point is the amount of electric potential energy that a unitary point charge would have when located at that point. At different point electric potential will be different, irrespective of point where we take. So, I don't think so it would be same until a resistor is reached. If there is a potential difference between two points then only charge flows, if we assume, potential to be same till resistor is reached, then how could we expect current in between?

Comment: If you had formed the tetrahedron out of six, 1 meter lengths of fine wire with a resistance of 1 Ohm/meter, there would be no visible distinction between conductors and resistors, but the circuit diagram of Olin Lathrop above would still be correct (and very useful!) The length and shape of conductors in a wiring diagram need not bear any relationship to reality.  Only the connectivity matters.

Comment: @Vinay: There is no need to explain more how the tetrahedron was drawn in 2D above.  That *REALLY* should be obvious, especially when looking at the right diagram in the question.  We have to assume at least some minimal intelligence of the reader when writing answers here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thanks for stating what I wanted to say but didn't manage to ;)

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I don't feel shy in asking what I don't know. I can understand, even you can't go to that depth of basic to explain from A, B, C... Anyway thank you for your precious time, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are looking at the resistance between A and D. Temporarily remove (in your head) the resistor across CB. Look at the paths ABD and ACD. They are equivalent. So the potential at point B and C are equal, by symmetry.

Now when you put the resistor CB back, because the potential difference across BC is 0, no current flows across it. So the original setup looks as though the resistor CB is missing.

You can easily solve for the resistance from there.

Comment: so, it's (1/1+1 + 1/1+1 + 1/1)^-1

Comment: @nervxxx.According to you, by symmetry potential at A,C,D should be same as at B, thus current should also not flow through AB and BD also. I don't think that would give correct answer.

Comment: @VINAY So, can you give me your answer please?

Comment: @VINAY what are you talking about? You put a potential difference across A and D. Obviously the potentials at A and D are different. Don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @nervxxx. According to you by symmetry potential at A and B should be same isn't it?

Comment: @VINAY don't use the word symmetry if you don't know what it means. In my analysis, I connect, for example, a battery across points A and D. OBVIOUSLY point A and point D will be have different potentials. The point (forgive the pun) is that the paths ABD and ACD are equivalent, in other words, you can't really distinguish between the two paths, so B and C must be at the same potential.

Comment: The system has a reflection symmetry defined by the plane containing A, D and the midpoint of the line connecting B and C. Since the reflection swaps B and C, they must have the same potential. The corresponding symmetry for A and D is broken by the fact that A and D are set at different potentials.

Comment: @nervxxx: According to you what is symmetry?

Comment: @VINAY What you instead mean by symmetry is that putting the battery between points AB must give the same current as putting the battery between points AD or AC or BD or so on.... which is TRUE. That gives the conclusion that no matter which 2 points you measure the resistance from, the value will be the same. But that is a separate issue altogether.

Comment: @nervxxx. Pardon me, I didn't understand your point.

Comment: @nervxxx: It would be better if you can explain (in your answer), how symmetry helps in predicting potential at two different points to be same?.